# Einführung in + Akk. und Vertiefung in + Dativ

Tags: dative, accusative

Warum sagt man "Einführung in **die** theoretische Philosophie", aber "Vertiefung **im** Privatrecht". Ich kann es leider grammatikalisch nicht nachvollziehen. Worin besteht der Unterschied?

Comment: Ich würde übrigens eher *Vertiefung des Privatrechts* sagen als *Vertiefung im Privatrecht* (was Deine Frage aber nicht unberechtigt macht).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, so heißt die Vorlesung :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eine Einführung führt dich in das Thema ein. Vorher warst du nicht im Thema, danach bist du drin. Es ist also eine klare Ortsänderung.
Wenn du dann drin bist, dann kannst du innerhalb des Themas tiefer gehen. Du bist aber schon drin. Also relativ zum Thema keine Ortsänderung.
„Vertiefung ins Privatrecht“ geht auch, klingt aber so, als ob man von „draußen“ ins Thema geht, nicht innerhalb des Themas tiefer. Außerdem klingt es für ein Universitätsmodul (und daher kommt der Name) vielleicht etwas zu umgangssprachlich.